# Can anyone explain why listAdapter does not take a generic argument?

Tags: java, android, generics, listadapter

I looked on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html and saw that `ListAdapter` is a pubic interface. From that i know `ArrayAdaptor` implements `ListAdaptor`. To create an instance of `ArrayAdaptor` of reference type `ListAdaptor`, my code was:

```
ListAdapter adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

(this compiled fine).

My question is why is why `ListAdapter` does not take any generic arguments?

I tried comparing this to creating an array list with `List` (a public interface) reference. To do this my code was:

```
 List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Can anyone explain the differenes between initialization process of the two?
List seems more intuitive, since if the parent is generic, the child should be too.

Comment: what's the parent of ListAdapter? what do you mean?

Comment: I meant like list is the "parent" of array list in the same way list adapter is a "parent" of array adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by not generic?  The interface is a very generic one-  it can be an interface to any type of data.  It doesn't even force you to a particular data structure for that data, like an array or a cursor.

Do you mean why doesn't it take a generic argument?  Because ListAdapter is actually more generic than that-  it doesn't care what type of data is in your list, so it doesn't require the generic type.  Notice that none of its functions requires it to know the type of the data.  While List does because it provides a bunch of functions that require you to know the type, such as add and remove.

Comment: that makes sense. Should of specified generic argument

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayAdapter<T>` implements `ListAdapter`. This means that it abides by the contract of ListAdapter. In this case this simply means that it implements the methods `areAllItemsEnabled()` and `isEnabled(int position)`.

There is no reason that ListAdapter should take a generic type, because these two methods don't involve the generic type.